# Debugging an XP bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working awhile on making this code, but I can't seem to make it work like I want it to. I wanted a prompt to come up, ask for how long you've worked on a topic, then give the correct width on the progress bar.

Edit: widthGenerator creates the popup, but I can't seem to have the variable width in widthGenerator() transfer to Move() as Move's width.

Here is my code:

```
<body class="w3-container">
<div class="w3-progress-container w3-round-xlarge">
    <div id="myBar" class="w3-progressbar w3-round-xlarge" style="width:1%"></div>
</div>

<button class="w3-btn" onclick="move()">Click Me</button> 

<script>
function widthGenerator() {
var question = prompt("Enter number of hours worked:", "Enter here");
  if (isNaN(question) == false) {
      var width = (question * 2.33463);
      break;
  } else if (isNaN(question) == true) {
    question = prompt("That is not a number; Enter the number of hours worked:", "Enter here");
    break;
  };
}
function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
    var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
var width = widthGenerator()
function frame() {
    if (width >= widthGenerator()) {
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        width += 0.1; 
        elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Are you getting an error? Include what is going wrong in your post.

Comment: fixed it to describe what the issue was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `return` statement in your widthGenerator() function:

```
function widthGenerator() {

    var question = prompt("Enter number of hours worked:", "Enter here");
    if (!isNaN(Number(question))) {
        var width = (question * 2.33463);
    } else {
        question = prompt("That is not a number; Enter the number of hours worked:", "Enter here");
    }

    return width;
}
```

I didn't want to tinker too much with your code but note that it is possible the user will never enter a number based on how widthGenerator() is written.

Comment: That would work, but another question I have is how would I stop the width incrementation in Move, so it only goes up to the amount of width?

Comment: Is there a for loop you forgot to include? Usually incrementers and break statements suggest a for loop. Also there seem to be other issues with your code. I think you will need a separate question. My answer to the question in this post above seems to be correct

Comment: Probably. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

This code makes sure, that the user is asked for a valid number, till he gives it. It is also a bit cleaner. And I removed the break as it is not a valid syntax, if you are not inside of an switch.

You may want to remove the timeout in your code, as it will be proccesed after asking for width anyway. And clearing imeout from within of it win't do anything. Lastly I removed function frame, reason 1 beeing, that it was created for every call of `move()`, but secondly and mostly, it is unecesery as you can use an anonymous function for this type of job.

```
function widthGenerator() {
    var question = prompt("Enter number of hours worked:", "Enter here")
    while(isNaN(question)){
        question = prompt("That is not a number; Enter the number of hours worked:", "Enter here")
        //  this will make it loop, till the user gives a valid number
    }
    return (question * 2.33463)
}

function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar")
    var width = widthGenerator()

    //  You don't really need the timeout, since you can make the if anyway.
    var id = setInterval(function(){
        //  this is anonymous function, it is used if you need to pass a callback to 
        if (width >= widthGenerator()) {
            //  Clearing this timeout won't do anything as you allready did cleared it by calling it
            clearInterval(id)
        } else {
            width += 0.1
            elem.style.width = width + '%'
        }
    }, 1)
}
```

Feel free to ask any questions.